# Laravel returning view from controller view not found error

Tags: laravel, view

Hello i have two folders in resources folder in laravel one is front end and other is back end which is admin folder.But accessing views from admin folder generates error when accessing view via controller View [login] not found. here is my folder structure for admin panel.
Resources -> admin -> views -> login.blade.php
for front end
Resources -> views->welcome.blade.php

on Logincontroller

```
class Logincontroller  extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
     return view('login');
    
    }
}
```

i have tried also `return view('admin/login');`

but web route works perfectly

```
Route::get('admin/login', function () {
    return view('login');
});
```

and below Route generates error
Route::get('/login', 'Logincontroller@index');

Comment: this isn't how views are structured, they are in the `resources/views` directory ... if you want to have them some where else you would have to configure the application to know that

Comment: @lagbox i have configured the app thats why Route::get('admin/login', function () {
    return view('login');
}); works perfectly. if there is error please tell me

Comment: there is no view named `login` in `resources/views` that is why ... it only looks for views in `resources/views` ... if it isn't in there somewhere then it doesn't exist

Comment: You probably do have a view called `login` under `resources/views` or you somehow changed the root of your views. You should move your admin views in `resources/views/admin` and then you can access them via e.g. `view('admin.login')`

Answer (score 1):

The structure should be like : resources/views/admin/login.blade.php

And the usage should be like : return view('admin.login');